# How to save geo data in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation, elastic-stack

How do I index a document with below data in elasticsearch(geo datatype)?

```
<west>5.8663152683722</west>
<north>55.0583836008072</north>
<east>15.0418156516163</east>
<south>47.2701236047002</south>
```

I tried geo_point and its working for lon and lat's, not sure how to save this data. any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You'll have to use the [geo_shape datatype](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html#geo-polygon) and convert your XML (I assume) semi-points into a line string or polygon before sync.

---

I'm gonna go with a polygon here.
Let's visualise the conventional [cardinal directions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_direction):

```json
             North (+90)
               |
(-180) West  ——+—— East (+180)
               |
             South (-90)
```

geo_shape expects GeoJSON-like inputs so you'll need five coordinate points, the first and last of which are identical (according to the [GeoJSON spec](http://wiki.geojson.org/GeoJSON_1.0_RC_1#Polygon)).

Therefore, borrowing from [TurfJS](https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-bbox-polygon/index.ts) and going from bottom left counter-clockwise,

```json
const lowLeft = [west, south];
const topLeft = [west, north];
const topRight = [east, north];
const lowRight = [east, south];

return 
[ 
  [
    lowLeft,
    lowRight,
    topRight,
    topLeft,
    lowLeft
  ]
]
```

Finally, let's create our index and plug your numbers in

```json
PUT /example
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "location": {
        "type": "geo_shape"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```json
POST /example/_doc
{
  "location":{
    "type":"polygon",
    "coordinates":[
      [
        [
          5.8663152683722,
          47.2701236047002
        ],
        [
          15.0418156516163,
          47.2701236047002
        ],
        [
          15.0418156516163,
          55.0583836008072
        ],
        [
          5.8663152683722,
          55.0583836008072
        ],
        [
          5.8663152683722,
          47.2701236047002
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

Then verify that the center of your square if indeed inside of your indexed polygon:

```json
GET example/_search
{
  "query": {
    "geo_shape": {
      "location": {
        "shape": {
          "type": "point",
          "coordinates": [
            10.45406545999425,
            51.1642536027537
          ]
        },
        "relation": "intersects"
      }
    }
  }
}
```